# What is the name of the game called "Ace" in south Asia (specifically India)?

Tags: identify-this-game

This game has a standard deck of 52 playing cards. All the cards are dealt out to the players, and there can be any number of players.

The game goes like this:

First the player who has the Ace of Spades has to start the game by playing that card. Then each player plays a card of their choice matching the suit that was selected. If they already have a card in front of them, it's discarded first.

If any player doesn't have cards of the selected suit then he plays any card of his choice and then the player with the highest valued card will take all the played cards and add them to his hand, and then start a new round.

The game continues until only one player has cards remaining. That player is the winner.

Does anyone recognise this game?

Comment: I remember this game. I am from India and we called as ace itself.

Comment: I don't understand “if they already have a card in front of them”; how does it get there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found several references to it online as being called "Bhabhi":

http://s193890092.onlinehome.us/malton/bhabhi.htm

http://www.zymbiotic.com/bhabhi/rules

Also, someone on BoardGameGeek really likes it, so it must be bona fide:

http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/471299/the-perfect-card-game

Answer (score 0):

> The game continues until only one player has cards remaining. That player is the winner.

No, he is the loser. We place funny objects over him. Its called bhabhi (Sister in law) in Hindi. I am from Southern state of India. Here its called kazhutha (Donkey).

The loser becomes the donkey and he wears the funny item for the next game.

Answer (score -1):

We call it bondi in maldives ok.

Comment: Welcome to B&CG!  Do you have a link or source for the above?  Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Yes i know its name its "Bhabhi Thulla"

Comment: Can you provide any more information or clarification?  A link?  The other answer already provided the Bhabhi name, so is this a specific variant?